# svg text wiggling(shaking) problem during the transform animation

Tags: html, css, svg

During the transform animation, the text begins to shaking, after research, I realized that it depends on container viewport. If the viewport is small, then we can see that the text is shaking, if viewport is big, the text does not start shaking and animation runs smoothly.

Small viewport example:

```js
const groupList = document.querySelectorAll("svg g");
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

const containerViewport = [20,20];
// const containerViewport = [100,100];

container.style.width = `${containerViewport[0]}%`;
container.style.height = `${containerViewport[1]}%`;

// cannot change this
const increaseRatio = 0.1;

const values = [
    30, 70, 110
]

for (const [key, node] of groupList.entries()) {
    node.setAttribute("transform", `translate(29, ${values[key]})`)
}

setInterval(()=>{
    for (const [key, node] of groupList.entries()) {
        values[key] = values[key] + increaseRatio;
        node.setAttribute("transform", `translate(29, ${values[key]})`)
    }
},20)
```

```css
 .tick {
    color: #fff;
}
.line {
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: gray;" id="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 411 252" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">15</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" y2="0" class="line"></line>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">10</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" class="line" y2="0"></line>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">5</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" class="line" y2="0"></line>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Big viewport example:

```js
const groupList = document.querySelectorAll("svg g");
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

// const containerViewport = [20,20];
const containerViewport = [100,100];

container.style.width = `${containerViewport[0]}%`;
container.style.height = `${containerViewport[1]}%`;

// cannot change this
const increaseRatio = 0.1;

const values = [
    30, 70, 110
]

for (const [key, node] of groupList.entries()) {
    node.setAttribute("transform", `translate(29, ${values[key]})`)
}

setInterval(()=>{
    for (const [key, node] of groupList.entries()) {
        values[key] = values[key] + increaseRatio;
        node.setAttribute("transform", `translate(29, ${values[key]})`)
    }
},20)
```

```css
 .tick {
    color: #fff;
}
.line {
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: gray;" id="container">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 411 252" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">15</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" y2="0" class="line"></line>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">10</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" class="line" y2="0"></line>
        </g>
        <g>
            <text x="0" y="-10" style="" class="tick">5</text>
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="381" class="line" y2="0"></line>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I tried to increase svg viewBox, but it does not matter, text still shaking.

Video demonstration:
https://youtu.be/d_aIIDfCHB0

Comment: The 0.1 is marked as not being changeable - but it is very small and the interval of 20ms is quite small too (when thinking about how many frames might get painted in a second). Have you CSS animations which might shove more onto the GPU and is there a reason for the 0.1 not being allowed to be changed. You may be getting rounding errors when the device pixels and CSS pixel try to match.